# What kind of apps can perform better on multi-core cpu?

Tags: multicore

I just want to know that if there is a simple way of judging what kind of apps can perform better on multi-core cpu? Such as Memcached, redis, MySQL, Cassandra and so on.

Comment: Any app that processes a dividable workload, and whose author(s) have expended the effort to divide that workload. One example: video encoding (e.g., mencoder). 

Does this really belong on Superuser?

Comment: Thank you but I just want to look at this question from the point of programming

Comment: From the point of programming, you'd look at the algorithms used in the compute-heavy portions of the app, and ask "can this workload be divided between N mostly-independent computational threads?"

Comment: @derobert, that gives me a clue thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Anything where independent calculations can be performed...

Financial Applications and Graphics Rendering Applications come to mind.

Comment: Doesn't it need any particular programming library/method?

Comment: @Mickey Shine: There are numerous different libraries and methods of doing multi-threaded computation, so no one particular one is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Bruteforcing cryptographic hashes.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of apps that could benefit, but if you want to boil it down to just one important thing then I would have to say any application that takes advantage of a multithreaded architecture. If developed correctly the application threads could be ran simultaneously on different cores. The trick is to make sure they do not serialize from excessive locking.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example.

Anything that has a computation that can be broken down.  Say you need to add all numbers from 0-800,000 and you have an 8 core machine.

You can set up 8 loops to add the numbers 1-100,000; 100,001-200,000, etc... run one on each core, save the results in a variable. i.e. loop1,loop2,etc. Then add the variables together when the loops terminate for your answer.

Comment: Of course, before going through the extra work of multithreading, one should perform simple algebraic optimizations :-P